# mPDF turning square image into a circle

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Is it at all possible to have an image be a circle in mPDF?
Looked all over and couldn't find any clear answers.

For me this image shows up fine, except that its a square and this should make it a circle.

css

```
img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

php

```
$inputPath = '../web_content/cool_cat.jpg';
<div class="profile_img">
    <img src="'.$inputPath.'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: border-radius probably is not supported within PDF. I did this with TCPDF and clipping masks, example https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_034/

Comment: Try using inline styling for your class definition rather an external file

Comment: I'm not sure I got your request :) but maybe this helps:http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a way to work around this by using the image as a background image instead of an  element.

So within the PHP file which creates the pdf with mpdf I just made a div that can take the image path as $inputPath. Seems to work fine now.

**HTML / PHP**

```
<div class="profile_img" style="background-image: url('.$inputPath.');"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile_img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: medium;

    overflow: hidden;

    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
 }
```

Comment: 5 years later, and Chrome now seems to have an issue with the Print Preview window. Using this method works for the PDF generation, but something about the background- tags break how it generates the preivew, which means it will pritn with no background images. Very strange, I've spend hours debugging but have no idea how to solve it. So I've reverted to standard <img> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Border-radius is not supported on IMG elements.

See [Supported CSS](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) in mPDF manual.

Unfortunately, this cannot be faked even with placing the image into a div which supports the border-radius element.

```
<div style="width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px; 
    border: 2px solid maroon; 
    overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="assets/butterfly_ProPhoto.png" />
</div>
```

[image: image in border-radiused div]

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @jjyj did not work for me so I had to find another solution.

First I tried creating an  with an included  tag. Fail.

Then I thought maybe creating the image directly with PHP would be easier. Fail.

Then I found another nice trick that will not work in every situation but in my case works perfectly.

Solution: Create two divs and then move one up with negative margin.

```
<div><img src=image.png style="width:49mm;height:49mm;margin:0.5mm;"></div>
<div style="margin-top:-50mm;"><img src=mask.svg style="width:50mm;height:50mm;"></div>
```

Before:

[image]

Merged:

[image]

As you can see I used a mask with a little white border and applied a little margin to the original image so that no edges of the below image shine through the mask.

Obviously the mask is intended to be used on white backgrounds - I added a grey background for demonstration.